# How to copy a Target in XCODE 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode5

1. I want to make copy of my existing app target with different name.
2. The changed name should reflect in simulator and info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Select your project, now on the left panel select your target and click Duplicate.

[image]

To edit the name of the scheme just click on manage schemes under the scheme selection.

Comment: I have done in that way.But in scheme selection tab its not showing my edited name .Its  showing "projectName copy".I don't want that copy .I want my edited name

Answer (score 0):

After adding a duplicate target to existing target .If you want to change the name ,Then select that target under manage scheme --->tap enter key on that it will coem to edit mode .And you can change the name.